# Are PHP5 objects passed by reference?

Tags: php

I can't seem to get any consistent info on this. Different sources appear to say different things and the venerable php.net itself (*appears*) not to explicitly state this - although, I must admit, I only had a quick look.

In cases where I am passing around 'heavy' objects, I need to pass by reference, but I don't want to keep typing:

```
function foo(TypeName& $obj)
```

if I can get away with simply

```
function foo(TypeName $obj)
```

So what does the standard say?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Objects are passed (and assigned) by reference. No need to use address of operator.

Granted what I typed is an oversimplification but will suit your purposes. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) states:

> One of the key-points of PHP5 OOP that
>   is often mentioned is that "objects
>   are passed by references by default".
>   This is not completely true. This
>   section rectifies that general thought
>   using some examples.
>
> A PHP reference is an alias, which
>   allows two different variables to
>   write to the same value. As of PHP5,
>   an object variable doesn't contain the
>   object itself as value anymore. It
>   only contains an object identifier
>   which allows object accessors to find
>   the actual object. When an object is
>   sent by argument, returned or assigned
>   to another variable, the different
>   variables are not aliases: they hold a
>   copy of the identifier, which points
>   to the same object.

For a more detailed explanation (explains the oversimplification as well as identifiers) check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331519/php-object-by-reference-in-php5/9332219#9332219).

Comment: Thus you can pass a reference of an object indentifier?

Comment: When you pass an object, you are still passing "by value". However, the "value" is NOT the object itself. The value is the object identifier, which accessors (->) use to find the object. So whenever you pass an object or assign an object to something else, it "feels" like passing by reference. It "feels" like an alias when using ->. But technically it is not an alias, but a copy of a value where the value is an object identifier. If it were an alias, reassigning to a completely different value would change all the aliases to that new value, but you will see that it does not make them aliases.

Comment: @OCDev so every time that object gets cloned? Kinda resource wasting.

Comment: @JohnSmith - No, the object does not get cloned. The "value" that is copied is NOT the object itself. The value that gets copied is a tiny object identifier that allows them to find the same object in memory. Passing or copying objects around between variables (into and out of functions, etc) is very much like copying integers. These "integers" (so to speak) represent locations in memory to find the actual object. The full blown object is NOT copied when any of this happens. (It just sits there in memory.) Nor are the different variables aliases of one another.

Answer (score 8):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

> You can pass a variable by reference
>   to a function so the function can
>   modify the variable. The syntax is as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> <?php
> function foo(&$var)
> {
>     $var++;
> }
>
> $a=5;
> foo($a);
> // $a is 6 here
> ?>
> ```
>
> Note: There is no reference sign on a
>   function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions
>   alone are enough to correctly pass the
>   argument by reference. As of PHP
>   5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is
>   deprecated when you use & in
>   foo(&$a);.

And from [What's New in PHP5](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1714):

> In PHP 5, the infrastructure of the
>   object model was rewritten to work
>   with object handles. Unless you
>   explicitly clone an object by using
>   the clone keyword you will never
>   create behind the scene duplicates of
>   your objects. In PHP 5, there is
>   neither a need to pass objects by
>   reference nor assigning them by
>   reference

So therefore the only time you need to use the `function foo(&$var)` syntax is if $var might not be an instance of a class.

Comment: I'm taking pedantic exception to your statement "So therefore the only time you need to use the <<pass by reference>> syntax is if $var might not be an instance of a class".

There is another important situation where you do want to use a by-reference for an instance of a class...

If - as a result of calling a function, you want the parameter you passed to refer to (point to) a *different* instance, then you would need the function to take a parameter passed by reference, and in the function you would assign that parameter to a different instance.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a little more precise, the value of an object is passed by value, but the value of an object itself is a pointer.  This is different from just passing a reference.

On http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php the example listed is nice.  In the first set, $a = NULL; doesn't affect $b since $a was just a pointer.  In the second set, $c = NULL; causes $d to be NULL as well since $d is a reference to $c.

```
<?php
class A {
    public $foo = 1;
}  

$a = new A;
$b = $a;
$a->foo = 2;
$a = NULL;
echo $b->foo."\n"; // 2

$c = new A;
$d = &$c;
$c->foo = 2;
$c = NULL;
echo $d->foo."\n"; // Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object...
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5, all objects are passed and assigned by reference.

In PHP 4, you still need to specify where you want objects passed by reference, by explicitly using the `&` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **yes**. From [Objects and references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php):

> One of the key-points of PHP5 OOP that
>   is often mentioned is that "objects
>   are passed by references by default".
>   This is not completely true. This
>   section rectifies that general thought
>   using some examples.
>
> A PHP reference is an alias, which
>   allows two different variables to
>   write to the same value. As of PHP5,
>   an object variable doesn't contain the
>   object itself as value anymore. It
>   only contains an object identifier
>   which allows object accessors to find
>   the actual object. When an object is
>   sent by argument, returned or assigned
>   to another variable, the different
>   variables are not aliases: they hold a
>   copy of the identifier, which points
>   to the same object.

What matters is that, in the case that worries you, you'll never be making a copy of an object unless you explicitly use the **clone** keyword in the function call. Whether it's an alias or an identifier doesn't change this fact.

Comment: For further clarification, an example I have a PSR-7 Response object passed around as `functionName(\Response $response)` behaves like I where writing this `functionName(\Response &$response)` in PHP 5+? When this is true then I have to re-think everything in my small project.

Comment: @ZsoltOroszlány In [PSR-7](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/), responses are required to be immutable by definition. That means that implementations have to call `clone` explicitly, as in e.g. [Slim framework](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.7.0/Slim/Http/Response.php#L182).

Answer (score 2):

Just an example where passing "objects" by reference is useful:

```
class RefTest1
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct(RefTest2 &$ref = null)
    {
        $this->foo =& $ref;
    }
}

class RefTest2
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct(RefTest1 &$ref = null)
    {
        $this->foo =& $ref;
    }
}

class RefTest3
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct(RefTest2 &$ref = null)
    {
        $this->foo =& $ref;
    }
}

class DoCrossRef
{
    public $refTest1;
    public $refTest2;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->refTest1 = new RefTest1($this->refTest2);
        $this->refTest2 = new RefTest2($this->refTest1);
    }

    public function changeReference()
    {
        $this->refTest1 = new RefTest3($this->refTest2);
    }
}
```

At the end `RefTest1` holds a reference to `RefTest2` and the other way around, also if the `RefTest2` object did not exist at the time `RefTest1` was created.

After calling `DoCrossRef->changeReference()`, the `RefTest2` objects also holds a reference to the new `RefTest3` object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes from PHP5 onwards, objects are passed by reference. No need to do that explicitly.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php

> In PHP 5 there is a new Object Model. PHP's handling of objects has been completely rewritten, allowing for better performance and more features. In previous versions of PHP, objects were handled like primitive types (for instance integers and strings). The drawback of this method was that semantically the whole object was copied when a variable was assigned, or passed as a parameter to a method. In the new approach, objects are referenced by handle, and not by value (one can think of a handle as an object's identifier).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example confirming that objects are passed by reference.

```
<?php

// discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715026/are-php5-objects-passed-by-reference#_=_
class A {
    public $foo = 1;
}

class B {
    function inc($obj) {
        $obj->foo++;
    }
}

$objA = new A();
$objB = new B();
$objB->inc($objA);

echo "[" . $objA->foo . "]"; // Outputs [2]
```