# Pass an object into another class by reference

Tags: php, oop

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715026/are-php5-objects-passed-by-reference) question but it doesn't fully answer the question I have.

If I do this:

```
$obj1 = new ObjectOne();
```

and then this:

```
$obj2 = new ObjectTwo($obj1);
$obj2->someFunction();
```

Where `someFunction()` modifies the attributes of the object passed into it, will both `$obj1` and `$obj2->passedInObject` both in effect be updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the following code, and it works as expected. The var in `MyObject` gets incremented in the original object.

```
<?php 
class MyObject {
     public $var;
}

class MyObjectTwo {
    public $objVar;
    function __construct($aObj1) {
        $this->objVar = $aObj1;
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        $this->objVar->var++;
    }
}

$obj1 = new MyObject();
$obj1->var = 5; // Originally set to 5

$obj2 = new MyObjectTwo($obj1);
$obj2->someFunction();
echo $obj1->var; // Prints 6
```