# assign an instance of a class to a new object in php

Tags: php

Following is an example in **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)**:

```
<?php

    $instance = new SimpleClass();
    $assigned   =  $instance;
    $reference  =& $instance;

    $instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';
    $instance = null; // $instance and $reference become null

    var_dump($instance);
    var_dump($reference);
    var_dump($assigned);
 ?>
```

I cannot understand the result :

```
NULL
NULL
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) {
   ["var"]=>
     string(30) "$assigned will have this value"
}
```

Anyone can tell me the answer, I think the three var point the same instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$instance = new SimpleClass(); // create instance
$assigned   =  $instance; // assign *identifier* to $assigned
$reference  =& $instance; // assign *reference* to $reference 

$instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';
$instance = null; // change $instance to null (as well as any variables that reference same)
```

Assigning via reference and identifier are different. From the manual:

> One of the key-points of PHP5 OOP that is often mentioned is that
>   "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely
>   true. This section rectifies that general thought using some examples.
>
> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to
>   write to the same value. As of PHP5, an object variable doesn't
>   contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object
>   identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.
>   When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another
>   variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of
>   the identifier, which points to the same object.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331519/php-object-by-reference-in-php5/9332219#9332219) for more info.

Comment: But i think that the $assigned hold an identifier point to the $instance , then the $instance is assigned null

Comment: No, it holds an identifier `to the object pointed to by $instance`, not to `$instance`.

Comment: oh, I know.. It means that $assigned holds an identifier point to the object, while the $instance is null, the object not change?

Comment: `$instance = NULL` overwrites the identifier in `$instance` but `$assigned` still holds its identifier. The object is still intact.