# PHP, does assignment use double memory for a variable?

Tags: php

If I have a large object and assign another variable to that object, does php create two objects, or does it use a pointer internally?

for example:

```
<?php
$myObject = new Class_That_Will_Consume_Lots_Of_Memory();
$testObject = $myObject;
```

In this example will i be using 2 x the memory footprint of a `Class_That_Will_Consume_Lots_Of_Memory` instance or will it be 1 of those and a pointer?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter: one object and a pointer/reference (and in fact, here, two pointers/references, since the first is one as well).

To get a new object, use `clone`.

Related: [Are PHP5 objects passed by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715026/are-php5-objects-passed-by-reference)

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Yes, for things that are normally passed by value. Instance of objects, however, are passed by reference pretty much by definition.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: the & is not needed in php5. I believe it raises a warning or a strict notice, too.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast this was PHP4. …

Answer (score 0):

Objects in PHP5 are passed by reference, arrays and other types passing is based on Copy on Write technique:

```
$a = ['a'=>'b'];
$b = $a; // Here we used 1x memory
$b['x'] = 'y'; // Now it become 2x memory
```

You can use `memory_get_usage()` to debug memory usage.