# php - Access outer class from an anonymous callback

Tags: php, class, callback, anonymous-function

I have a code like this:

```
class Server {
  private $stopper;

  public function setStopper() { $this->stopper = TRUE; }

  public function startServer() {
    $consumer = new Consumer();
    $consumer->onConsume(function($data) {
      global $consumer;
      // some processing
      if( ?? ) { // how to access stopper here??
         $consumer->stop();
         // also how to access stopServer() here??
      }
    });
    $consumer->consume();
  }

  public function stopServer() { ... }

}
```

This code is in a file that should run forever unless the `setStopper()` is called. So far I have `set_time_limit` to stop the code after a while. But I need to implement `setStopper` way so I can stop the server whenever needed, not "after a while".

I need this because,  the `onConsume` is connected to a streaming API and runs the anonymous call back whenever new data is available and I don't want kill the php app on timeout due to some lock issues. I want to gracefully stop the server.

Can anyone please tell how to access the `stopper` or `stopServer` inside the callback? Can I use following syntax?

```
...(function($data) use ($this) {...
```

I also thought of storing the class value inside callback, but the `setStopper` is called dynamically and the value might not be updated!

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

**Follow Up:** [php - Dynamically update Singleton class' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374529)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) around the `$consumer` object as well as the lexical object `$this` (if you're using PHP < 5.4, you need to rename `$this` to something else, because you cannot `use($this)`):

```
 $self = $this;
 // You may not need to do this, I cannot remember off-hand whether 
 // closures have access to private variables or not
 $stopper = $this->stopper;
 $consumer->onConsume(function($data) use($consumer, $self, $stopper) {
  if( $stopper ) {
     $consumer->stop();
     $self->stopServer();
  }
});
```

See Example #3 on the linked to manual page.

I should also note here for completeness that if this is a long-lived process, then the objects being referenced inside the closure will hang around long after the function exits.  For instance:

```
function makeAdder($x) {
    return function($n) use($x) {
        return $x + $n;
    };
}

$adder = makeAdder(5);
echo $adder(2); // Output 7
echo $adder(5); // Output 10
echo $adder(4); // Output 9
```

This is a classic example of a closure.  Normally, once the `makeAdder` function returns its inner variable `$x` will fall out of scope and be ready for garbage collection.  Since it is however bound inside the anonymous function's scope, it will hang around indefinitely (until the script's termination) *or* the reference to the containing scope is also released (i.e. via `unset($adder)`).  This means that once your function is called, extra references to `$consumer`, `$this` and `$stopper` will hang around until the class instance itself is destroyed.

Not being aware of this can lead to some serious performance issues.

Comment: does updating `stopper ` in `setStopper` affect the `$stopper` inside the callback? Is everything "by reference" in php?

Comment: Objects are, yes.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715026/are-php5-objects-passed-by-reference)

Comment: Okay then! I will update my code and verify if its running, thanks, and 'll let you know

Comment: Hey, mind if I ask one more question? If I use this as a singleton class, and I execute another php script that gets the instance and sets the stopper, it doesn't actually stop the consume! Can I know why?

Comment: I mean if the whole thing works by reference, and if I understand the working of singleton class, setting the stopper should stop the server right? But it doesn't! The stopper is still `false` even after I call the `setStopper`

Comment: I moved the other question as a new one and as a follow up. Thanks, your's answers the OP, so no more bugging

Answer (score 0):

the same problem here i use output buffers from ob_start/ob_end_flush
and one function i have should be dynamic (however parameters i push into should insert them in an array for later use for parsing buffers using **$buffer**)
in the parser associated to ob_start at a time i have these lines of code from one array full of data :

```
if(!empty($this->__b2))
        array_filter ($this->__b2,function($var)use(**&$buffer**){
                $buffer = preg_replace("/<\/body>/i", $var.'</body>', $buffer);
        });
```

I use a only one class singleton ,and i use "::" a lot.
How you see  in my case
 **array_filter was out of order without &$buffer**