# php - Dynamically update Singleton class' value

Tags: php, dynamic, singleton

This is a followup question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373288)

If I declare this as a singleton class:

```
// Server.php
class Server {
  private $stopper;
  private static $instance;

  public static getInstance() { 
    if(!isset(self::$Server)) 
      self::$Server = new static();
    return self::$Server; 
  }

  public function setStopper() { $this->stopper = TRUE; }

  public function startServer() { 
    $self = $this;
    $consumer = new Consumer();
    $consumer->onConsume(function($data) use($self, $consumer) {
      // some processing
      if($self->getStopper()) { // always false
         $consumer->stop();
         $self->stopServer();
      }
    });
    $consumer->consume();
  }

  public function stopServer() { ... }

}
```

And used following script to start the server:

```
// start.php
$server = Server::getInstance();
$server->startServer();
```

And following script to set the stopper:

```
// stop.php
$server = Server::getInstance();
$server->setStopper();
```

It doesn't work: the stopper is still false (tried `echo`ing)! Also I have tried using sessions instead.

```
// start.php
$server = new Server();

session_start();
$_SESSION['server'] = $server;
session_write_close();

$server->startServer();

// stop.php
session_start();
$server = $_SESSION['server'];
$server->setStopper(TRUE);
```

But running the stop.php throws following error: `Undefined index: server`

Comment: what does the code in   public function setStopper() { ... } look like ?

Comment: since you are calling these functions in 2 different files, it is possible that the scope of variables is getting lost. Basically you need to create 2 separate instances of the class for the 2 files which are completely different from each other.

Comment: Sorry, I just copied the code from my other question. Fixed it!

Comment: Also, I am not sure if sharing the instance in a session like this will work since it is possible that the session will just convert the instance into a string which can't be used again the way you are trying to do that.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Can you elaborate on your comment? because if I read it correctly that'd kill the whole purpose of the code!

Comment: @Maximus2012 Please, can you give an alternative solution then, to achieve the same?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Look at the first comment that I made. The 2nd about the session means that you can't share an object of a class across a session like this. You can do that for string and other values but not for objects of a class like this so the session approach may not work in your case.

Comment: Can you post the body of your `getInstance()` function?

Comment: Could you possibly combing the code for start.php and stop.php in one file ?

Comment: @Sammitch code updated

Comment: @Maximus2012 yes you can, php serializes/unserializes objects when writing/reading sessions. The only restriction is that you cannot serialize `resource` types, but you can also work around that with `__sleep()`/`__wakeup()` or the Serializable interface.

Comment: I am not entirely sure actually.

Comment: @Maximus2012 @Sammitch Friends, please, I need to know how to update the `stopper` from another file! Can you please give a solution?

Comment: That is the thing that I am not sure about. I was thinking if you could do that from the same file so that you could use same instance but looks like that is not the case here.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Yes, the start.php connects to a streaming API and runs forever, so I need a way to stop this externally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Maximus2012 and @Sammitch.

I got an idea from the following thread from Google groups

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phirehose-users/dvCZ9EvCNA8/nOiv3m2ByAEJ

I used an external `.txt` file to store a flag and set the stopper instead of all this fiasco ;)

**Update**

I found out why its not possible to work with singletons in this case. Every time php is invoked, a separate process (or thread, depending on the server) is created to handle that request i.e. separate process(or threads) for `start.php` and `stop.php` and they can't access same singleton due to "inter process privacy"!

But if I run start.php and stop.php as a single process it works, as expected!