# how do i reassign values to a php object passed to a function

Tags: php

if I pass an object to a function in PHP, it's passed by reference, and if I set that object to a new object, it doesn't 'stick'. How can I assign a new object to an object that's passed in preferably without iterating over all properties?

e.g.:

```
function Foo($obj)
{
    // do stuff and create new obj
    $obj = $newObj;

    // upon function exit, the original $obj value is as it was
}
```

Comment: *"if I pass an object to a function in PHP, it's passed by reference"* -- this is not correct. Read the differences: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php. If you want to pass an object to the function and want the function to be able to replace the object then you have to use a reference. Or, better, let the function return another object and do the replacement in the calling code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PHP5 objects passed by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715026/are-php5-objects-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I pass an object to a function in PHP, it's passed by reference

In PHP an object is passed by "pointer-value" e.g. a pointer to the object is copied into the function arguments:

```
function test($arg) {
    $arg = new stdClass();
}

$a = new stdClass();
$a->property = '123';
test($a);

var_dump($a->property); // "123"
```

To pass by pointer-reference, prefix an ampersand sign to the parameter:

```
function test(&$arg) {
    $arg = new stdClass();
}

$a = new stdClass();
$a->property = '123';
test($a);

var_dump($a->property); // Undefined property
```

But you should avoid pointer-references as they tend to confuse and instead just return the new object:

```
function test($arg) {
    return new stdClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to return the new value then you can access the new value:

```
function Foo($obj)
{
    // do stuff and create new obj
    $obj = $newObj;

    // upon function exit, the original $obj value is as it was
    return $obj; 
}
```

Comment: This will just return a variable that also still points to the original object.  To return a new instance you need to clone the object otherwise there is little benefit to returning the object here (other than nicer to read code).